# Search the internet from desktop using the super (windows) key?

Tags: gnome, internet, search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YK9A.jpg)

On Windows, you press the key and the search functionality will search the computer as well as the internet (albeit with bing and edge). How do I get that here? At the moment it only searches the computer and the software center. I remember being able to do this on Mint a few years ago.

Comment: try finding a Gnome shell extension that does what you're looking for. Or possibly that's a Cinnamon feature, if it worked on Mint (which uses the Cinnamon desktop by default)

Comment: Ive tried looking for an extension but I cant find any for GNOME 42. Do you think there will be one soon? How hard would it be to make one?

Comment: [Surf](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4661/surf/) seems to do what you want, not sure if it's availabe for Gnome 42, and I can't check because extensions.gnome.org is down right now